# d3js v4: Only show labels on x-axis

Tags: d3.js

I'm creating a stacked bar chart. I would like to show only the tick's label text on the x-axis, but without the ticks and the horizontal x-axis line.

How do I go from here?

```
g.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this is the CSS:

```
.axis path, .axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
}
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([1, 10]).range([10, 390])
svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,50)')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
```

```css
.axis path, .axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="80"></svg>
```

Comment: Great and useful, thank you for this! just helped me in customizing my D3 bar chart