# Why does scale.linear() still works on d3.js v4 in this example

Tags: d3.js

I was curious why scale.linear() still works on d3.js v4 in this example =>  [d3js v4: Only show labels on x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360808/d3js-v4-only-show-labels-on-x-axis).

When I changed it to scaleLinear() instead, then I get error message saying `Uncaught TypeError: d3.scaleLinear is not a function`.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention, I just edited that answer to version 4. Answering your question: what happened is that I was carelessly using D3 v3 in my answer, as you can easily see by the script tag: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min‌​‌​.js"></script>`. It was the version `3.4.11`.

Comment: For verifying what's the D3 version if you don't easily find the script reference, just do `console.log(d3.version)`. For instance, here at Stack Overflow the green bar chart and the line chart you see when you go to your *profile* page are made using D3. In your profile, open the console and type `d3.version`. You'll get: `"3.2.4"`.

Comment: I see, thank you for kindly teaching me how to check the version!

Comment: No worries, and thank you again for bringing that to my attention. I'm getting older and inattentive, OP is clearly saying that they're using v4 in that question!