# How to control the spacings of the x Axis label positions in a stacked bar chart?

Tags: d3.js

I took bits from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199108/d3-v4-scaleband-ticks) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360808/d3js-v4-only-show-labels-on-x-axis) solutions.

I then do the following to show my x axis label ticks:

```
var x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(.1).domain(d3.range(1993, 2002));
svg.append("g")
   .attr('class', 'axis')
   .attr('transform', 'translate(-10,' + (height - 20) + ')')
   .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
```

However, I then get the following output where x axis ticks are shifted further to the right each time like if their gap doesn't match the bar's.

[image]

Comment: would need to see the full code, especially for how you draw the boxes and the dataset. you only have nine boxes, and 10 labels.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, actually I have also 10 labels it just overflows to the right because of this mismatching spacing.

Comment: The problem is also I dont want to share my codebase with the world yet. If you are willing to help me please pass me your Github username and I will be happy to share the code with you. Then we can explain in this post what was going on and the answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet shows how the rects and axis's ticks line up correctly.

Need to be careful on how d3.range generates arrays, in that d3.range(1993, 2002) will create [1993, 1994, ... , 2001].

Also, I'm not sure why the g element that contains the X axis was shifted left, so that is set to 0

```js
var width = 800
    var height = 100
    
    //this makes an array 1993 to 2001. Is that what you want?
    var data = d3.range(1993, 2002) 
     
    var x = d3.scaleBand()
     .range([0, width])
     .padding(.1)
     .domain(data);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
    
    svg.append("g")
        .attr('class', 'axis')
       //.attr('transform', 'translate(-10,' + (height - 20) + ')')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (height - 20) + ')')
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
     
    svg.selectAll('rect')
     .data(data)
     .enter()
     .append('rect')
     .attr('x', d => x(d))
     .attr('y', 0)
     .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
     .attr('height', x.bandwidth())
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough S.O to 'comment' but I think it may be helpful to use the xScale:
-in the xAxis (something like...
xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
        .scale(xScale)
)
-in the x position of each bar ( something like...
  'x', d => xScale(year)
)
-in the width of each bar, seems like you might need to use something like...
('width', x.bandwidth())

looks like the xScale in the (1)axis and (2)bars are not working as expected together.
Maybe this helps?!